# Running specific parameterized nose tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing, nose

Currently using `nose_parameterized` to run a large number of integration tests. When looking to deploy to production or something similar, this works wonderfully. The drawback is that we're now at the point where we've got enough tests that it takes a real amount of time for them to run (think about 30s)

When we're writing new tests/code, it's typically keyed to a new parameter. I'm wondering if there's a way to say that at test time we only want to run tests with certain parameters to cut down on development time. To get a bit more concrete:

```
class TestParsers(unittest.TestCase):
    @parameterized.expand(create_parameters())
    def test_scrape(self, parser, url, attr, value):
        # Runs test

def create_parameters():
    return json.dumps(open('tests.json'))
```

Assume that `tests.json` looks something like this:

```
[["a", 1, 2], ["a", 2, 3], ["b", 1, 2], ["b", 3, 4]]
```

The workflow is that when I'm working on a new feature I'm adding the test cases that start with `b`. I'm wondering if there's something like a commandline argument that could be passed along like `nosetests --runonly=b` to limit the time for running tests.

The hacky solution of commenting other tests isn't a good one here particularly because we're actually creating the parameters from the combination of many files.

Comment: Did u find a solution as I'm facing the same issue too

Comment: @IslamTaha Unfortunately no. Just ended up making a test and deploy config. Not ideal, but it sort of worked.

Comment: I found a way by passing the test case name

Comment: @IslamTaha similar kind of solution then. Neither particularly nice. One of us should probably go make a PR if we have time.

Answer (score 0):

There is as far as I know no out of the box solution for your problem but maybe you can have a look at @attr

---

http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html